# Access to ros_comm source code in fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've noticed that in Fuerte when you install the package ros-fuerte-ros-comm (and other low level ros packages) the installation follows the FHS layout, and the source code is no longer installed.

What is the easiest way to have access to this source code? (Somehow making sure that the source and my installed code are the same version).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46792/access-to-ros_comm-source-code-in-fuerte/) by [toniOliver](https://answers.ros.org/users/1236/tonioliver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2012-10-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [usual way](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslocate) to find the correct source *should* be:

```
$ roslocate info ros_comm --distro=fuerte
```

However, that does not seem to work for `ros_comm` in Fuerte.

On my system, leaving off the `--distro` option yields this:

```
$ roslocate info ros_comm 
- svn:
    local-name: ros_comm
    uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_comm/trunk
```

That is probably not the exact version released with Fuerte. Assuming that the repository is at least correct, I'd recommend checking this out, instead:

```
https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_comm/tags/fuerte/
```

The recommended way to manage source overlays is with [rosws](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws.html). There are already answers for questions about `rosws` on this same Q&A site.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1